# Name Azure SQL Server during creation from Azure portal

Tags: sql-server, powershell, azure

When creating a SQL Server through the Azure portal, it generates a random server name like abcsomejunkcharactersxyz.database.windows.net. While I realize this is some level of security through obscurity... Is there no way to control the name of the SQL Server in Azure?

Optimally, this would be controllable at either creation time or via a rename and able to be done in an automated fashion through PowerShell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't, the naming isn't for security, it's to ensure uniqueness - what if two users wanted the same name? Which user should get it?

Comment: While this is the correct answer (you can't), I find this a poor argument for why we can't name them. Every other service we get to name and they have to be just as unique. I understand the difficulty in *renaming* these once you have databases on them, but why not allow us to specify the initial name (and never change it from there) while still enforcing unique checks (again, like **every other** Azure service)?

Comment: Is there a DNS-like feature set within an Azure subscription that can alias the SQL Server?

Comment: See this [blog post](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/greg_low/archive/2013/01/21/working-with-aliases-for-windows-azure-sql-databases-in-sql-server-management-studio.aspx) for details of aliasing in Azure.

Comment: As already pointed out, every other service allows naming, this is simply a case of a nice to have which hasn't yet been done.  imo the correct answer is 'because MS haven't implemented it, and it's waaaaaay down the list'.

Answer (score 18):

In the [new Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com/) is it possible to set your own SQL Server instance name.

[image]

Comment: This is an actual solution! I'm not sure if the ability to name your server will stay in the new portal (since it was to avoid arguments about names http://sqlblog.com/blogs/greg_low/archive/2013/01/21/working-with-aliases-for-windows-azure-sql-databases-in-sql-server-management-studio.aspx) but it works for now!

Comment: Is it possible to RENAME a server?